# Fetch data from Table 1 column's count in Table 2

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

```
Table 1 :

ID  City             State
1   NewYork          NY
2   Oklahama         OK
3   california       CA
4   new jersey       NJ
5   Las Vegas        LA

Table 2 :

ID  City 
1    NewYork          
2    NewYork          
3    NewYork          
4    Oklahama
5    Oklahama
```

NewYork is 3 times and Oklahama is 2 times in table 2.
So I want to fetch City List from Table 1 which Cities are used less then 5 times in Table 2

So what will exact query in Mysql?

I am using below code :

```
select *
from  Table1
where Table1.city in
    (select Table2 .city,count(*)
     from Table2
     having count(*) < 5
     group by Table2.city )
```

Comment: I was looking for Query So By Mistake i wrote Jquery. Please vote my Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a in clause with a subselect

```
    select  * from  table1
    where city in (select  city from table2 having count(*) < 5 group by city)
```

In your code you have a space between the Table2  and .city

```
select  * 
from  Table1  where Table1.city in   (select  
              Table2 .city,count(*) from Table2 having count(*) < 5 group by Table2.city )
```

must be

```
select  * 
from  Table1  
where Table1.city in   (select  Table2.city
                        from Table2 
                         group by Table2.city
                         having count(*) < 5   )
```

no space between tablename and column ..

you can seee http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/556cb6/10

Comment: Its not worked for me.I am comparing city from table 1 to Table 2.I want city list from table 1 which is used in table 2 less then 5 times.

Comment: I have update the answer ..looking the sample provided you question was not so clear .. l

Comment: I checked this it is showing me error on group by clause.Just to be clear again I want to fetch City from table one which city is another table less then 5 times.Lets say NewYork is in table one.and in table two there are four row which contains NewYork 3 times.So i want data from table one which is less then 5 in table 2.Thanks.

Comment: You can show me the error  message  please ...i have update the answer removing distinct (not needed)

Comment: I am getting this error: Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by city'

Comment: please update you question and add the exact code you are using .. so i can evaluate the real code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115659/discussion-between-csharp-and-scaisedge).

Comment: It is showing me same error as earlier.near group by.I think it needs join ween two table on City.because data is from table 1's column's count in another table2 for city.So basically second select query from table 2 is not working.we need to write code so we can get at least get cities which repeated less then 5 times.and after that we can apply "in" in query.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot.It also worked for me.Thanks a lot again@ scaisEdge !.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
select Table1.city
from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.city = Table2.city
group by Table1.city
having count(Table2.city) < 5
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b93bf/1/0)

Comment: Thank you so much @Tony.This worked for me.This is actually what i want.